# How do I find the smallest value in an array of Complex numbers a + ci

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to write a method which finds the smallest value in an array of Complex numbers a + ci, where a and c are both doubles. a is the real part and ci is the imaginary part. I'm trying to have it go through the array and compare each object a + ci and b + di. I was going to start by comparing the real parts and if the real parts were equal, then I would move on to the imaginary ones such that complexNumberOne < complexNumberTwo if a < b or if (a==b), c < d.

So far I have a method that can determine the smallest number in the array, but only by comparing the real parts:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

private boolean arrayTest = false;

public double min(Complex[] arr) {
    double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i].getReal() < min) {
            min = arr[i].getReal();
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

But my method to find the smallest element according the the aforementioned conditions seems to go nowhere:

```
public Complex smallest(Complex[] arr) {

    Complex min = new Complex();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {
        while(!arrayTest) {
            if(arr[i].getReal()<arr[i+1].getReal()) {
                arrayTest=true;
                min = arr[i];
            }else if(arr[i].getReal()==arr[i+1].getReal()) {
                while(!arrayTest) {
                    if(arr[i].getImaginary()<arr[i+1].getImaginary()) {
                        arrayTest=true;
                        min = arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;` you need `double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: The `while` loop around `if (arr[i].getimaginary() < ...` is wrong.  If the `if` doesn't set `arrayTest` to `true` the first time around, nothing ever changes inside the loop that could later cause that `if` to ever set `arrayTest` to `true`, and so you've got an infinite loop.  Maybe just get rid of that `while`, for starters.

Comment: That's not the usual definition of "small" with respect to complex numbers. There does not exist a total ordering of the complex numbers, but it is common to given them a partial ordering based on their distance from origin, i.e., (r * r + i * i -- no need to take the square root if you're just comparing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so many loops and nested loops? 
A single scan of the array will do:

```
public Complex smallest(Complex[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return null;

    Complex min = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].getReal() < min.getReal()) {
            min = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i].getReal() == min.getReal()) {
            if (arr[i].getImaginary() < min.getImaginary()) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Also there is no need for that boolean flag `arrayTest`.
The code could be further *simplified* if you don't mind a long condition:

```
public Complex smallest(Complex[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return null;

    Complex min = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].getReal() < min.getReal() || (arr[i].getReal() == min.getReal() && arr[i].getImaginary() < min.getImaginary())) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```